# how do i call a vbs script from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I am trying to execute a vbs script from vb.net.  I want to be able to pass an argument as well as wait for the script to finish before continuing with the .net code.

In vb6 I would write it like this:

```
Public ws, rv
rv = ws.Run(exePath & "sleep04.vbs 123", 1, True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class:

```
var p = Process.Start(exePath & "sleep04.vbs", "123")
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Or, for more specific parameter definitions:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
psi.FileName = "Firefox"
psi.Arguments = "-new-tab " & ws.URI
Process.Start(psi)
```